# Center tooltip & hold in place on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

At this site [videon](http://ryanspahn.com/Videon-Central-2/about.html)

I have implemented a tooltip script that shows different images when it's parent image is hovered over. Though the tooltip images are not centered directly over the parent images.

Can anyone provide insight on what I need to change to make the tooltip image appeared center over it's parent?

Here is the javascript function powering the tooltip...

```
// Load this script once the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Get all the thumbnail
        $('div.thumbnail-item').mouseenter(function(e) {

            // Calculate the position of the image tooltip
            x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

            // Set the z-index of the current item, 
            // make sure it's greater than the rest of thumbnail items
            // Set the position and display the image tooltip
            $(this).css('z-index','101')
            .children("div.tooltip")
            .css({'top': y + -400,'left': x + -115,'display':'block'});

        //}).mousemove(function(e) {

            // Calculate the position of the image tooltip          
        //  x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        //  y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

            // This line causes the tooltip will follow the mouse pointer
        //  $(this).children("div.tooltip").css({'top': y + -400,'left': x + -105});

        }).mouseleave(function() {

            // Reset the z-index and hide the image tooltip 
            $(this).css('z-index','100')
            .children("div.tooltip")
            .animate({"opacity": "hide"}, "fast");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the code here that you currently use to position the tooltip to save our time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the mouse event position in calculations. The thumb offset().left plus 1/2 it's width will be center